# p4 sync -f does not overwrite opened files

Tags: synchronization, perforce

I have checked out a file from my perforce depot and made some changes in it but did not submit those changes.

Now,

p4 sync -f does not overwrite my changes by getting latest revision of from perforce.

I want my code to be overwritten here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`p4 revert`](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_revert.html) to abandon your changes.

Comment: `p4 clean' is another alternative.